# Will a fingerprint created using a canvas 2D render give the same result on two devices with matching hardware and software?

Tags: html5-canvas, fingerprinting

If I draw something in the browser using a canvas 2D render, and use this to create a fingerprint, would two devices, such as two newly purchased iPhones (same model) give the same fingerprint, or are their minute hardware differences which would cause both devices to produce different fingerprints?

Thanks

Comment: In one hand you ask about two devices with the same hardware, and then you introduce the possibility there is a difference in hardware. Sounds like the question becomes can two newly purchased iPhones (same model) have different hardware.

Comment: My meaning is when the processors, etc., are being created, are there tiny differences in the hardware (due to manufacturing errors, etc.) which would cause two "identical" devices to give different fingerprints.

Comment: If that was the case, then the hardware would be "different".

Comment: OK. My question is asking is this true in the real world? Would two (for example) "identical" iPhones give the same or different fingerprint?

Comment: Yes they should give the same, but why does that matter to you? Unless you're in lab conditions and able to force the exact same conditions on both devices from buying, there will certainly be some entropy that would make it possible to tell apart two devices. And it's also possible that two different hardware produce the same result. What are you after with this info?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The idea with fingerprinting is you want to be able to identify individual devices with some confidence, but if so many people (for example) are using the latest iPhone with the same version of iOS, that will cause a lot of devices to produce the same fingerprint.

Comment: That's why when you do finger print you don't use a single source of entropy. You also look at things like the list of installed fonts, browser settings, and the obvious browser version (e.g by feature detection), ip address, geolocation etc. Adding all these together you end up with more entropy than just what the canvas API triggers and you reduce the possibility of false positives.

Comment: Yes, understood, but my question is specifically about canvas 2d rendering. If what you're saying is correct, the answer to my question is "Yes".